# Is this generic cadence chart from Kostka/Payne generally accepted?

Tags: cadence

I was perusing my Kostka/Payne book for something when I noticed this chart which I either never paid attention to or forgot :-)

[image]

I understand its meaning, but it leads to some interesting possibilities that I never really thought of. Cadences that would seem to be at home in a 'modal' style, like...

```
Plagal: ii | I
Half  : I  | IV
Half  : I  | ii
```

Is this chart generally accepted?

I thought a half cadence *must* end on a `V` and that a plagal cadence was defined by the 'first chord' being `IV` or `iv`.

Comment: Thousands of theorists teach using the Kostka/Payne. Those thousands of theorists *hate* that they teach with the Kostka/Payne.

Comment: This is not completely consistent with other classical texts I've seen.

Comment: @Richard I’m one of the professors that teaches from it, but I just don’t get the hate that so many have for it. I’d probably prefer to use Aldwell/Schachter, and I was definitely impressed with Clen/Marv when I taught at a school that uses it, but I just don’t think K/P is that bad. Oh well, this chart is definitely not their most shining hour.

Comment: Any opinions on Elie Siegmeister's _Harmony and Melody_? That two volume textbook and Piston's _Counterpoint_ are the two textbooks I like best in my modest collection. I don't count Gjerdingen and Caplin, those don't seem like textbooks to me. (You probably know I'm not a teacher.)

Comment: Would bII7-I count as an authentic cadence, then? It's rad tritone substitution, but....

Comment: @Dekkadeci - Absolutely Yes.  I've gone through Db7(no5)-C, Db7(b5)-C, and Db7-C cadences.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis - I'm not sure exactly... because if you say yes, [this](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/86757/conflict-kostka-payne-cadence-chart-vs-authentic-cadence-in-natural-minor) seemingly comes to a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, that chart only makes sense when you take in the rest of the context. I *think* they’re just trying to point to the primary distinction between conclusive and progressive cadences, with a side issue about presence of a leading tone.

I don’t know anyone, including K&P, that regularly talk about half cadences ending on anything other than V. One could *maybe* make an argument for vii°, but you’d have to do a lot of fancy footwork to claim that a phrase can “cadence” on a dissonant harmony. However, there is at least one other kind of Plagal cadence discussed by K&P using ii instead of IV: ii6/5 – I. Of course, as they point out themselves, this could very easily be interpreted as a IVadd6 instead of ii6/5, and that’s probably a less dubious interpretation.

So I don’t think it’s a great chart, especially out of context.

Comment: "Straight Outta Context!" ...just a little NWA joke there :-) Probably the first thing I do when presented something like that chart is apply it out of context. I wrote out every diatonic pairing for each category just to see what I would get.

Comment: Haha, actually could lead to some interesting musical ideas.

Comment: Gangsta Madrigals, anyone?