# What is the theory behind this chord progression with two chords from the minor scale of the same key?

Tags: theory, chord-progressions

I came across a lovely piece with the following chrod progression:

- Body:
  D Dmaj7 G Em F#m G Em D
- Ending:
  D D7 Bb C D D

From the body it looks like D major scale, but in the ending two chords from D minor scale are added before proceeding to the D major chord, like a picardy third, altohugh the piece is not in D minor.

My question is how does the ending work in theory? Like, why does D-D7-Bb sound smooth? Is it a picardy third? (also, how do we notate it by roman numbers?) Are there other examples using the same trick?

Thanks :)

Comment: Poss. dupe for 'is there a name for this cadence?'

Comment: @Tim You are right! I just realized that and flagged it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's modal interchange. Bb is bVI and C is bVII, both borrowed from D minor.

Maybe one could think of D7 as of V/iv and then bVI substituting iv?

See also: [Is there a name for this cadence? (bVI bVII I)](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/82179/is-there-a-name-for-this-cadence-bvi-bvii-i)